# How to print QTableWidget on printer?

Tags: qt

I have big size QTableWidget.
I want to print it including headers, but QTableWidget doesn't have print() method. How can I implement it?

Answer (score -1):

The information you want is provided in the [Printing with Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/printing.html) documentation page.  In particular, pay attention to the **Painting onto a Page** section.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a table with HTML and by using QTextDocument's setHtml() method you can set the tables to document then you can use the print() function of document for a continuous print with page numbers.

Comment: brief example? Specifically for the "set the tables to document then you can use the print() function..." bit